# UserControls not rendering

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, user-controls

Okay, to start, I'm pretty inexperienced with WPF and XAML, so any pointers or advice would be greatly appreciated.

I have a scheduling program that I'm working on that I need some help setting up.  I had things working previously, but it wasn't organized correctly.  I had UI elements in my ViewModels that I would add to a StackPanel at the initialization of the MainWindow.  Generally not MVVM style coding.  So I made some views (UserControls) to display the things I have, and most everything broke.

Basically, I have a Schedule ViewModel that has some parameters and a list of a different Room ViewModels.  Each Room ViewModel has a RoomSchedule ViewModel that contains a list of RoomEvent ViewModels.

I'm trying to write controls for the things that need displaying.  I've created a Schedule view, which has a list box of Room views, and the Room view uses the RoomEvent view to display the events of the room.  The Room view uses the WPF Extended Toolkit's TimelinePanel, the rest of the controls are pretty much basic controls.  The general idea has been: a model provides data to the ViewModel, which massages that data to what needs to be displayed.  So an Event should know how to display itself, a Room should know how to display itself, and the Schedule should know how to display itself.

The problem I'm running into is: now that I've scooted everything from the xaml.cs or ViewModel files to their appropriate places, the controls aren't rendering at all.  I've been reading other SO postings where people have the same problem, but none of them seem to work for beginner stuff like this.  I think I'm close, it seems like all the controls are being created, and the DataContext's are being set correctly, but nothing is showing up.

This is, basically, what I have so far.  I left some of the xaml boilerplate stuff off for succinctness:

Schedule.xaml:

```
<StackPanel>
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Rooms}" >
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                 <localcontrols:RoomView ScheduleStart="{Binding ElementName=ScheduleControl, Path=DataContext.Start}"
            </DataTemplate>
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
</StackPanel>
```

RoomView.xaml:

```
<extended:TimelinePanel BeginDate="{Binding localcontrols:ScheduleStart}" EndDate="{Binding localcontrols:ScheduleEnd}"
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=mRoomSchedule.mScheduledEvents}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <localcontrols:EventView />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControls.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
</extended:TimelinePanel>
```

EventView.xaml:

```
<Border BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Black" extended:TimelinePanel.Date="{Binding mStartTime}" extended:TimelinePanel.DateEnd="{Binding mEndTime}">
    <TextBlock Background="{Binding mColor}" Text="{Binding mEventID}" />
</Border>
```

The `ScheduleStart` and `ScheduleEnd` are dependency properties defined in RoomView.xaml.cs.  My thinking was that Schedule would have `Start` and `End` properties that would be set in its constructor, and the `RoomView`s in the `ListBox` would bind to those properties to set the TimelinePanel's `BeginDate` and `EndDate`.

Comment: `="{Binding localcontrols:ScheduleStart}" ` That's completely wrong.  You have too much waving around in here for me to know the actual solution.  This is why creating a minimal prototype that isolates the issue is always the first step before asking.  Anyhow, side note, Snoop is a great tool for examining your bindings at runtime.  You'll see what you can actually bind against, which can give you a hint of how to get the data you need in there.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your bindings are wrong. When I need to bind to a dependency property I use the **ElementName** feature of binding to say which control I want and I give the root node a name, in this case **Root**. It's one way to solve it.

```
<UserControl
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Weingartner.Controls"
    x:Class="RoomView"
    x:Name="Root">


    <extended:TimelinePanel
       BeginDate="{Binding ElementName=Root, Path=ScheduleStart}" 
       EndDate="{Binding ElementName=Root, Path=ScheduleEnd}"
    >
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=mRoomSchedule.mScheduledEvents}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <localcontrols:EventView />
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControls.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
    </extended:TimelinePanel>



</UserControl>
```

Comment: That makes more sense than what I was doing, but it didn't help.  Thank you.